# Basis and dimensions of two vectorial spaces.

Tags: linear-algebra, analytic-geometry

Determine a base and the dimension of:

a) U and W

b) U + W

c) U $\cap$ W
$$
U =  \left\{ (x,y,z) \in R^{3} : x+y+z = 0 \right\} \\
W =  \left\{ (x,y,0) \in R^{3} : x,y \in R \right\} 
$$

I see that both sets can be described as points in a plane...

Basis:

For U:
$$
\alpha = (1,1,-2)\\
\beta = (0,1,-1)\\
\gamma = (2,-2,0)\\
\alpha,\beta,\gamma \in x+y+z = 0\\
\text{ }\\
\alpha - \beta = (1,0,-1)\\
\gamma - \alpha = (1,-3,2)\\
\text{ }\\
B_{u} =  \left\{ (1,0,-1), (1,-3,2) \right\} 
$$

For W:
$$
B_{w} =  \left\{ (1,0,0), (0,1,0) \right\} 
$$

a) 
$$
dim(u) = dim(w) = 2
$$

b)
$$
dim(u+w) = dim(u) + dim(w) - dim(u \cap w) =\\
dim(u+w) = 2 + 2 - dim(u \cap w)\\
$$Since U and W are planes with different inclinations, based on their normal vectors: $(1,1,1),(0,0,1)$ respectively, we can affirm that their intersection is going to be a line, with $dim = 1$
$$
dim(u \cap w) = 1
$$
Hence:
$$
dim(u+w) = 2 + 2 - 1 = 3
$$
c)
$$
dim(u \cap w) = 1
$$

I don't know the best way to get the basis and dimension in this case... But there was what I've done. Please tell me if there's an easier way to do it. What if they were not planes, but the all $R^{3}$ space, I would have had a little bit of trouble on solving it!

Thanks

Comment: For part $a$, $\alpha - \beta= (1,0,-1)$, which is consistent with $x+y+z=0$

Comment: @SquirtleSquad ur right. Got confused with signals... I'll edit it. Ty

Answer (score 1):

Your work is fine for parts $(a)$ and $(b)$. Notice that $U\cap W$ is the set of all vectors whose third component is zero and are orthogonal to the vector $(1, 1, 1)$. That is, $(x, y, 0)\cdot(1,1,1) = x + y = 0$ or the set of all vectors such that $x = -y$.

In other words, $U\cap W = \{(-y, y, 0)\,\colon y\in \Bbb R\}$. Can you find a basis for this space? Notice that the dimension is in general the number of vectors in a basis, so once you have determined a basis, picking up the dimension is straightforward.

Comment: Thanks for the commend buddy. $(-1,1,0)$ is a basis for $U \cap W$ so $dim(u \cap w) = 1$. But should I really do that to show that the intersection will be this line? I showed before that their intersection is going to be a line, hence, $dim(u \cap w) = 1$ isn't that right?

Comment: @BrunoReis, That's right. What you said is fine, but a bit informal. For some, it may not be obvious why based on their normal vectors the intersection of the two spaces will be a line. Something like this would please more skeptics.

Comment: thanks a lot! I'm starting to get into that kind of math formalism...